# Why is there even spacing between peaks in light waves?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, wave-particle-duality

It is hard for me to understand the propagation of light or matter as waves. If I try to think of a wave as a stream of particles, I wonder why the particles would be evenly spaced; that is, why is there even spacing between peaks in light's intensity? And why is there even spacing between the peaks in a particle's wave function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is there even spacing between peaks in light's intensity?

There isn’t necessarily even spacing. Maxwell’s equations in vacuum admit a wave solution. The wave equation can take many forms, including non repeating or aperiodic forms. Even for purely sinusoidal plane waves you can have circularly polarized waves where the intensity is constant throughout.

It is often convenient to decompose a given wave into a sum of frequency components where every component is periodic. However, that is a computational convenience and does not imply that all waves are periodic.

Typically, waves which do display even spacing do so because of the characteristics of the source. If the source oscillates at an even frequency then the wave spacing will also be even. Other sources will behave differently.

Comment: This is very helpful. I haven't been exposed to these different types of waves that aren't so uniform. I could not figure out why all waves would behave this way. It doesn't make sense because it's not true.

Comment: @supernova yes, textbooks present the pure sinusoid wave because it is the easiest. But even standard FM radio is an example of a deliberately generated wave without even spacing.